# Using post_filter with Spring Data Elasticsearch's NativeSearchQueryBuilder

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am in reference to the `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` spring data elasticsearch.

What is the way to set a `post_filter` to a `nativeSearchQuery`?

It seems possible with the native elasticsearch search api: see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html) and as follows:

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("index1", "index2")
        .setTypes("type1", "type2")
        .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
        .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("multi", "test"))             // Query
        .setPostFilter(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("age").from(12).to(18))   // Filter
        .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

But I haven't found any way to do it in Spring data elasticsearch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `post_filter` is used implicitly when you call the [`ElasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(SearchQuery query, Class<T> clazz)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplate.html#queryForPage-org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.SearchQuery-java.lang.Class-) method. It will check if the `SearchQuery` parameter contains a `filter` and if it does, it will call `setPostFilter()` with that filter on the native `SearchRequestBuilder`.

So you can construct your query using the `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` like this:

```
private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(matchAllQuery())                     <--- your query
    .withFilter(termFilter("name", "somename"))     <--- your post filter
    .build();

Page<SampleEntity> sampleEntities =
    elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery, SampleEntity.class);
```

Under the hood, `ElasticsearchTemplate` [will set the `post_filter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/416daef2f92734d0d1b5681265d719b9f1c347d5/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplate.java#L315-L316) with the above `term` filter on the `name` field.

Comment: Definitely the answer.