# Spring data elasticsearch Filter aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have the following JSON query that is working and doing what I want:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "values": {
      "filter": { "term": { "gender": "Male" } },
      "aggs" : {
        "names" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "name", "size":10000 }
        }
    }
    }
  },
  "size":0
  }
```

It is retrieving all the different names present where "gener" field is equal to "Male". It is an example of a [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) in elasticseach.

I am now trying to write it with spring-data-elasticsearch and I have tried this:

```
    AbstractAggregationBuilder<TermsAggregationBuilder> agBuilder = AggregationBuilders.terms("name").field("name").size(10000);

    Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
        .withFilter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("gender", "Male"))
        .withPageable(EmptyPage.INSTANCE)
        .addAggregation(agBuilder).build();

    //Execute request over the cluster
    SearchHits<Person> hits = elasticClient.search(query, Person.class);

    //Retrieve the aggregation details
    Aggregations aggs = hits.getAggregations();
    ParsedStringTerms topTags = (ParsedStringTerms) aggs.get("name");
```

Note that `EmptyPage.INSTANCE` is the same as PageRequest.of(0,0), is a custom Impl to achieve that.

Unfortunately it's not doing what I want, since it's ignoring the `filter` clause, it's returning names of males and females.
I suspect that maybe the `withQuery` should contain another `Query` but I don't know how to pass another `NativeSearchQuery` to that method.

Versions I am using:

- Spring Data Elasticsearch: 4.0.3.RELEASE
- Elasticsearch Client: 7.6.2

How could I write the above json query with spring-data-elasticsearch?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar topic, same answer, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915571/using-post-filter-with-spring-data-elasticsearchs-nativesearchquerybuilder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter actually needs to be inside `withQuery()`.

```
Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("gender", "Male"))
    ...
```

`withFilter` serves another purpose, namely it is a [`post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/filter-search-results.html#post-filter).

Also note that the query you are building is slightly different than the one specified at the top of your question, it looks like the one below and is actually a more optimized version, because you're filtering the documents **before** doing the aggregation, instead of doing the aggregation on all documents and only consider the ones matching the filter. The end result is the same, but the performance is not.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "gender": "Male"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "names": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 10000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's right! It works. Thanks for the advise, I understand now the difference between each query.